# How to properly include a tikzpicture inside another tikzpicture?

Tags: tikz-pgf, horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment, diagrams, nodes

I have a command to create a sort of box that I use to write various things such as definitions or theorems. It involves writing the content of the box inside a `tikzpicture` to style the box the way I want (see minimal working example below).

The code is made by me off of bits I found on the internet and it certainly could be made very much better - but until now it has been working properly. That is, until I tried to include pictures in it. Nested TikZ environments are generally a bad idea but I do not see any other way to achieve the result I want. The command `\tikz` and the environment `tikzpicture` produce similar results.

In particular, the nodes do not appear quite at the position they are meant to (they are north east of where they should) and manually setting an anchor to them sends them way off at the left of the picture. Despite using `\centering` or the `center` environment, the picture is not centered horizontally.

It also looks like the vertical spacing above the text in the box is made wrong by the presence of the picture.

Any idea would be greatly appreciated, in particular I was thinking maybe it is possible to have TeX generate the TikZ picture first, independently of the fact it is nested, and then include it like with a `includegraphics` command (which works fine).

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{attachfile}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newlength{\saveparindent}
\AtBeginDocument{\setlength{\saveparindent}{\parindent}}
\newlength{\titlel}
\newsavebox{\boxcontent}
\newlength{\contenth}
\newcounter{saveequation}
\newcounter{savefootnote}
\newcounter{savefigure}

\newcommand{\boxedparagraph}[5]{
    \setcounter{saveequation}{\theequation}
    \setcounter{savefootnote}{\thefootnote}
    \setcounter{savefigure}{\thefigure}
    \settowidth{\titlel}{\textbf{#3} \textsc{#1}}
    \savebox{\boxcontent}{%
        \parbox[t]{0.88\textwidth}{
            \setlength{\parindent}{\saveparindent}
            #2\par\xdef\savedprevdepth{\the\prevdepth}
        }%
    }%
    \setcounter{equation}{\thesaveequation}
    \setcounter{footnote}{\thesavefootnote}
    \setcounter{figure}{\thesavefigure}
    \setlength{\contenth}{\ht\boxcontent+\dp\boxcontent}
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \draw[color = #5, fill = #5] (0, 0) -- (0, 0.3cm + \contenth) arc (180:90:0.3) -- (0.88\textwidth + 0.6cm, 0.6cm + \contenth) arc (90:0:0.3) -- (0.88\textwidth + 0.9cm, 0.3) arc (0:-90:0.3) -- cycle;
            \draw[color = #4, line width = 1.5pt] (0, 0) -- (0, 0.3cm + \contenth) arc (180:90:0.3) -- (0.5cm + \titlel, \contenth + 0.6cm) arc (-90:0:0.2) -- (0.7cm + \titlel, \contenth + 1.1cm);
            \draw (0.4, \contenth + 0.9cm) node[anchor = west]{\textbf{#3} \textsc{#1}};
            \draw (0.3, 0.2) node[anchor = south west, rectangle, text justified, text width = 0.88\textwidth]{\noindent
            
            #2
            
            \par
            \prevdepth\savedprevdepth};
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
}

\newcounter{definition}
\newcommand{\definition}[2]{
    \refstepcounter{definition}
    \boxedparagraph{#1}{#2}{Definition \thedefinition\ :}{orange}{yellow}
}

\begin{document}

\definition{Title of the box}{Text}

\definition{Title of the box}{
Text
\begin{center}
    \tikz{\draw (0, 0) circle(1); \draw (0, 0) node{$\bullet$};}
\end{center}
}

\definition{Title of the box}{
Text
\begin{center}
    \tikz{\draw (0, 0) circle(1); \draw (0, 0) node[anchor=center]{$\bullet$};}
\end{center}
}

\end{document}
```

[image: Minimal working example output]

Comment: Hi and welcome. Why don't you use the [CTAN tcolorbox](https://ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox) package which can do all of this and more?

Comment: you mention float in the title but you could not use a float in a tikzpicture, and no floats are used in your example document.  You could perhaps edit to clarify the title.

Comment: Oops sorry, it started out with a float

Comment: The usual way is to put the inner tuikzicture into a savebox and expand it in a node using \usebox.  tcolorbox does that automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your box made with a `tcolorbox` could be something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{attachfile}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newtcbtheorem[auto counter]{mydefinition}{Definition}{%
    enhanced,
    sharp corners=southwest,
    fonttitle=\bfseries,
    description font=\mdseries\scshape,
    attach boxed title to top left,
    boxed title style={colframe=white, colback=white},
    coltitle=black,
    colback=yellow,
    colframe=yellow,
    overlay = {\draw[orange, rounded corners, ultra thick] (frame.south west)|-(title.south)-|(title.north east);}
}{def}


\begin{document}

\begin{mydefinition}{Title of the box}{a}
Text
\end{mydefinition}

\begin{mydefinition}{Title of the box}{}
Text
\begin{center}
    \tikz{\draw (0, 0) circle(1); \draw (0, 0) node{$\bullet$};}
\end{center}
\end{mydefinition}

\begin{mydefinition}{Title of the box}{}
Text
\begin{center}
    \tikz{\draw (0, 0) circle(1); \draw (0, 0) node[anchor=center]{$\bullet$};}
\end{center}
\end{mydefinition}

\end{document}
```

As you can see, you use an environment with two parameters, the first one is the definition title and the second a label for further reference.

[image]